# Number of elements which belong to at most one of the sets.

Tags: combinatorics

If $n(A) = n(B) = n(C) = 13$, $n(A\cap B \cap C') = 2$, $n(B \cap C \cap A') = 4$, $n(A \cap C \cap B') = 3$ and $n(A \cap B \cap C) = 1$, then find the number of elements which belong to at most one of the sets.

How to make Venn diagram in this question?

Comment: What have you done?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am having confusion in representing  $n(A\cap B \cap C') = 2$ type terms in Venn diagram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Venn diagram that you can start with:

[image: Venn0]

The different regions in the diagram, labeled as $I,II,III,\dots,VIII$ correspond to the following sets:

$\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\text{Region}&\text{Set}\\
\hline
I&A'\cap B'\cap C'\\
\hline
II&A\cap B'\cap C'\\
\hline
III&A\cap B\cap C'\\
\hline
IV&A'\cap B\cap C'\\
\hline
V&A\cap B'\cap C\\
\hline
VI&A\cap B\cap C\\
\hline
VII&A'\cap B\cap C\\
\hline
VIII&A'\cap B'\cap C\\
\hline
\end{array}$

Remember what these sets mean when interpreted in words.  $A\cap B\cap C'$ is the set of things *in* $A$ **and** *in* $B$ **and** *not in* $C$.  To be in this set on the Venn diagram, that corresponds to the region inside of the circle $A$, inside of the circle $B$ and outside of the circle $C$.  In other words, the region labeled in my picture as region $III$.

Now, looking at the problem statement, you are told $n(A\cap B\cap C'),n(A\cap B'\cap C), n(A'\cap B\cap C)$ and $n(A\cap B\cap C)$.  Go ahead and fill these in to the venn diagram.

[image: First venn diagram]

From here, you want the total of all numbers in the circle for $A$ to be equal to $n(A)=13$.  What number should you place into region $II$?

> $13-2-1-3=7$

What about the other regions?

From all of this, you should be able to find out the number of elements in *at least one of the regions* as well as able to find out the number of elements in *exactly one of the regions*.  Do you in fact know anything about the universal set?

Without knowledge of the universal set, the question of *at most one of the regions* is unknown, since any number of elements might be in region $I$.

Comment: I think with respect to sets A, B and C, number of elements which belong to atmost one of the sets should be 7+6+5=18.

Comment: @Mathematics that is correct assuming that those are the only elements in the universe, however incorrect otherwise.  The sets could have been $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,13\}, B=\{1,2,3,14,15,\dots,23\}, C=\{1,4,5,6,14,15,16,17,24,\dots,28\}$ and we are interested only in the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,28\}$.  However, perhaps the universe are all numbers $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$.  How many of those are in *at most one of*.  Certainly, all of $\{29,\dots,100\}$ are in at most one of (in fact exactly zero, which still counts) in addition to those $18$ within $\{1,2,\dots,28\}$.